# How do I get the Breaking Dead achievement?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

The achievement Breaking Dead for the Bomb heist specifically states:

- In the Bomb: Dockyard heist, find the meth lab.

So where is this meth lab located? I checked all the buildings on both sides of the map, and I haven't seen any meth labs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breaking Dead achievement can be earned by finding the Meth Lab in one of the storage crates scattered throughout the main initial area.

Some things to note:

- The meth lab is not guaranteed to spawn
- It may take several retries to get the meth lab to spawn

  - An additional note: Start looking for the meth lab the moment you start the heist to make it easier to fight off the cops and drill through containers
- The achievement itself only requires you to step foot into the container with the meth lab. You DO NOT need to cook meth to get the achievement.

Answer (score 2):

The Meth Lab is in one of the containers on the ship. I believe you'll have to open the containers to find it.

However, you'll also need the ingredients to be able to actually cook the meth, and those can be found around the map.